# Reproducing folder named *

Tags: bash, ntfs, unicode

The question [Folder named *](https://superuser.com/questions/1708892/folder-named) was brought to my attention. I thought I could easily reproduce this by taking Git Bash and entering

```bsh
mkdir \*
```

At first I didn't look closely, I just saw a folder appear in Windows Explorer and I went ahead and delete it, which was successful. When I was about to write I comment, I repeated the experiment and I noticed that the character is not a `*` in Windows Explorer, but some dot.

[image: A dot folder]

Copy/pasting the folder name, it turns out the dot is not a `.` but Unicode `\uF02A` which belongs to a private set of Unicode characters.

Why doesn't my approach reproduce the result of the linked question?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet Windows' filesystem APIs (or maybe "git bash" itself) are disallowing the asterisk and substituting the dot. Apparently the NTFS filesystem's data structures allow some characters that Windows' filesystem APIs don't, so to get into the state in the linked question, you might have to mount that NTFS filesystem on a non-Windows OS and create the asterisk directory from there. "git bash", cygwin, and WSL may *look* Unixy, but their Unixness is only skin deep. Their filesystem writes still have to go through Windows filesystem APIs.

Comment: @Spiff According to the [accepted answer to the linked question](https://superuser.com/a/1708894/432690), WSL is deeper than that. Who's right?